# Find the only difference between two arrays in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays `a` and `b`. `a` always has one element more than `b`, and the arrays are mixed.

```ruby
 a = [1,5,7,2,4]
 b = [2,4,7,1]
```

I want to find the extra element in `a`. The output should be `5`.

What is the best approach in ruby? Is it good idea to use `loop`?

Comment: Did you try `a - b`?

Comment: It works, and return the difference array

Comment: Suppose `a = [1,2,3,4]` and `b = [5,6,7]`. What is the expected return value? What about `a = [1,2,3,4]` and `b = [1,1,1]`? There is nothing in the statement of the question that disqualifies these values for the two arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is the best built-in function to get what you expect

```
(a - b).pop
```

Comment: While it works, you don't need to use destruction. Simply use `first`.